# Why should I reserve an instance in Google Cloud? Any experiences?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

In Google Cloud, I have the option to reserve instances. See here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reservations-overview

*Note: I am not talking about Committed Use Discounts.*

I understand that by reserving an instance, Google guarantees the availability of this instance.

Do I need to be concerned that a Compute Engine instance is not available when I try to create it? Did anybody have bad experiences? Please share!

Comment: Among other things it is essentially a risk mitigation if you are expecting traffic spikes, for example. Like if you know you will see 300% higher traffic due to Black Friday sales you can reserve more compute resources for that time window so you can be assured they are immediately ready ahead of your traffic spike.

Comment: OK, thank you. Clearly you are operating in a different environment than we do. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Why should I reserve an instance in GCP ? to answer to your question. Reservations provide a very high level of assurance in obtaining capacity for Compute Engine zonal resources. This is the following cases: 1) Growth 2)Planned or unplanned spikes 3)Migration of a large number of virtual machine (VM) instances 4)Backup and disaster recovery, and also review this section [How reservations work](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reservations-overview#how-reservations-work). and also clarify what are your main goal from reservations of Compute Engine?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why should I reserve an instance in Google Cloud?**

To answer your question, there’s a lot key features for "Reservations of Compute Engine”
Reservations provide a very high level of assurance in obtaining capacity for Compute Engine zonal resources. You can use reservations to help ensure that your project has resources for future increases in demand, such as in the following cases:

- Growth
- Planned or unplanned spikes = (@CoryKramer explain this in the
  comment section)
- Migration of a large number of virtual machine (VM) instances
- Backup and disaster recovery

I think your question is more opinion based, but I suggest you try the "Reservations of Compute Engine” first, to explore and understand the key features of these reservations.

Actually I conducted a mini survey to my network using "Reservations of Compute Engine” , so far there’s no issue occured, you may also review this public documentation [how reservations work](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reservations-overview#how-reservations-work), pre-requisite [requirements](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reservations-overview#requirements) and also the [Billing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reservations-overview#reservation-billing) to explain here what reservations are billed.